# Integrating Ext JS with java backend

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, extjs

so I am still pretty new to Ext Js and java but I am working on a web project where I would like to integrate the front end stuff I made in Ext JS with my backend Java code that I wrote in Eclipse. I haven't found much else on here that helps much I tried just pulling in the folders/files I needed from Ext JS and incorporating them into my Java Script files in Eclipse but it did not work. Can anyone give me any pointers on where to go from here? I am also using Gradle as a build tool for my war file. Much appreciated!

P.S. I am not sure what code I would need to include to make this easier to answer but I certainly can as soon as someone lets me know what they need to see

Comment: Which backend framework are you using like java/python or anything else ?

Comment: Java Spring MVC for the backend framework